# awk field separator not working for first line

Tags: awk

```
echo 'NODE_1_length_317516_cov_18.568_ID_4005' | awk 'FS="_length" {print $1}'
```

Obtained output:

```
NODE_1_length_317516_cov_18.568_ID_4005
```

Expected output:

```
NODE_1
```

How is that possible? I'm missing something.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you are going through lines using Awk, the field separator is interpreted before processing the record. Awk reads the record according the current values of `FS` and `RS` and goes ahead performing the operations you ask it for.

This means that **if you set the value of `FS` while reading a record, this won't have effect for that specific record. Instead, the `FS` will have effect when reading the next one** and so on.

So if you have a file like this:

```
$ cat file
1,2 3,4
5,6 7,8
```

And you set the field separator while reading one record, it takes effect from the next line:

```
$ awk '{FS=","} {print $1}' file
1,2                             # FS is still the space!
5
```

So what you want to do is to set the `FS` before starting to read the file. That is, set it in the BEGIN block or via parameter:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {print $1}' file
1,2                             # now, FS is the comma
5
$ awk -F, '{print $1}' file
1
5
```

There is also another way: make Awk recompute the full record with `{$0=$0}`. With this, Awk will take into account the current `FS` and act accordingly:

```
$ awk '{FS=","} {$0=$0;print $1}' file
1
5
```

Comment: Suppose my first line is `Cal_Tno_V19_F04_R02`. How to use `awk` to print `Cal_Tno`, ie, to print first 2 fields with separator?

Comment: @Sigur this seems to be a completely different question to what I was answering here. It is better if you [ask a new question](/questions/ask) providing enough details!

Answer (score 3):

**awk Statement used incorrectly**

Correct way is

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "#{delimiter}" } ; { print $1 }'
```

In your case you can use

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "_length" } ; { print $1 }'
```

Comment: Just a reminder that if you try `print $0` it will produce the original line before field separators were applied. To print the whole line with new FS you must loop through the fields and print or use the shortcut of assigning a field, which recomputes the line with the FS: `{ $1 = $1; print $0}`

Answer (score 0):

Inbuilt variables like FS, ORS etc must be set within a context i.e in 1 of the following blocks: BEGIN, condition blocks or END.

```
$ echo 'NODE_1_length_317516_cov_18.568_ID_4005' | awk 'BEGIN{FS="_length"} {print $1}'
NODE_1
$
```

You can also pass the delimiter using `-F` switch like this:

```
$ echo 'NODE_1_length_317516_cov_18.568_ID_4005' | awk -F "_length" '{print $1}'
NODE_1
$
```