# awk returns two different outputs for the same input

Tags: bash, ssh, io-redirection, stderr

I'm trying to get first field value using awk field separator, but it is failing as below. Same is working fine when i'm trying with echo manually.

**Fail Case 1:**

```
[root@centos ~]# ssh -V | awk -F_ '{print $1}'

Output: OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022
```

**Fail Case 2:**

```
[root@centos ~]# ssh -V | awk 'BEGIN{FS="_"} {print $1}'

Output: OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022
```

**Working Case with "echo"**

```
[root@centos ~]# echo "OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022" | awk -F_ '{print $1}'

Output:  OpenSSH
```

I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855641/awk-field-separator-not-working-for-first-line) but it's not working in my case. What is it i'm failing to understand here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ssh -V` is writing its output to `stderr`, not `stdout`, so what you are seeing printed is the error stream that didn't go through `awk` at all.

An easy fix: redirect `stderr` to `stdout`.

```
ssh -V 2>&1 | awk -F_ '{print $1}'
```